# Exception during calling gensim?

Tags: python, gensim

I tried to load gensim in my code. Often it works fine. Today, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/6008168/tamouze/just.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gensim
  File "/project/6008168/tamouze/Python_directory/ENV2.7_new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, summarization, utils  # noqa:F401
  File "/project/6008168/tamouze/Python_directory/ENV2.7_new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/parsing/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .preprocessing import (remove_stopwords, strip_punctuation, strip_punctuation2,  # noqa:F401
  File "/project/6008168/tamouze/Python_directory/ENV2.7_new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/parsing/preprocessing.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gensim import utils
  File "/project/6008168/tamouze/Python_directory/ENV2.7_new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 44, in <module>
    from smart_open import smart_open
  File "/project/6008168/tamouze/Python_directory/ENV2.7_new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smart_open/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .smart_open_lib import *
  File "/project/6008168/tamouze/Python_directory/ENV2.7_new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 29, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/project/6008168/tamouze/Python_directory/ENV2.7_new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/project/6008168/tamouze/Python_directory/ENV2.7_new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
ImportError: cannot import name to_native_string
```

Im using python 2.7.14 and gensim 3.4.0.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't really occurring in `gensim`, even though that's how you found it. If you look at the stack, it's only triggered because `gensim` uses `smart_open` which in turn uses `requests`. It is in `requests` that the error happens.

If this was working, but now stopped, something likely changed in your environment, or how you're launching this code, related to the relationship between Python and the `requests` package.

For such errors, you should try searching Google for the final-two lines of your error stack – those most connected to the problem. Those are:

```
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
ImportError: cannot import name to_native_string
```

(These leave out the file path that's specific to you, but have a number of unique tokens likely to have also been reported by any others.)

A number of people have hit this, from a variety of other projects, but always triggered through `requests`. Some have reported re-installing `requests` (perhaps to ensure it's version 2.0.0 or later) helps.

If a simple re-install doesn't help, you could also try one or all of:

- uninstall, verify it's not present at all (that `requests` itself isn't found), then install – this could make sure you don't have overlapping redundant installations in different places that are both confusing the issue
- start from a fresh Python environment, reinstalling all packages
- double-check that all packages share the same Python2/Python3 compatibility

Comment: I was able to re-run my code by using the second option (start from a fresh python environment,etc) only.